# Can't execute flutter doctor command in flutter console

Tags: error-handling, dart, flutter

**When I run flutter doctor command in flutter console I'm getting this error. Can someone please help me out. I tried running in C drive used both the combination of Run as Admin (C and D drive)**

```
D:\flutter>flutter doctor
CreateProcessW failed 193

CreateProcessW failed 193
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    Command: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    #0      _ProcessImpl._runAndWait (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:485)
    #1      _runNonInteractiveProcessSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:631)
    #2      Process.runSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:66)
    #3      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:83)
    #4      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:321)
    #5      runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:296)
    #6      _runGit (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:449)
    #7      new FlutterVersion (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:23)
    #8      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64)
    #9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:99)
    #10     _HashVMBase&MapMixin&&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/dart:collection/compact_hash.dart:277)
    #11     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:87)
    #12     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:114)
    #13     FlutterVersion.instance (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart:170)
    #14     new Usage (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:26)
    #15     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:76)
    #16     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:99)
    #17     _HashVMBase&MapMixin&&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/dart:collection/compact_hash.dart:277)
    #18     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:87)
    #19     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:114)
    #20     Usage.instance (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:52)
    #21     flutterUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/usage.dart:20)
    #22     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:113)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #23     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #24     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
    #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
    #27     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
    #28     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #29     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:43)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #30     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50)
    #31     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:49)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #32     main (file:///E:/b/build/slave/Windows_Flutter_Packaging/build/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8)
    #33     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:277)
    #34     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall git, after that update your path to be able to run flutter from your command prompt.

for more details on how to update your path visit: [Update your path](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#update-your-path)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a spacing issue (eg. C:\Users\M Junaid) though flutter now supports spaces but try to move **ANDROID SDK** into Custom location where there are no spaces (eg. C:\Users\M.Junaid) in location path and update the variable **ANDROID_HOME** (value should be the same location you had moved it with no spaces).

Comment: Thanks,I crossed check all this but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial instead. I know it's a pain to watch it entirely but on the other hand you will be able to run a fresh and clean project from scratch.

[Flutter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0IbAIHAwnk&list=PLH4Fg3y9d-76Tvk3kO6oMda6XiCNBRO27&index=7&t=12s)

After that I ended up buying the full course and let me tell you I have not being disappointed.

Comment: That course shows  nothing on the flutter  setup